# Why are my inputs being skipped by the compiler?

Tags: c++, user-input

I'm relatively new to programming C++ and because my school syllabus dropped it 2 years back, I've recently started self-studying it on my own so I'm a noob. In the program I'm outputting directions to the user to input data correctly but when run, the compiler only shows the output and takes the input of the first line. The other two are skipped and the cursor goes straight to the last cout line. There aren't any errors the compiler is giving me.I've also tried putting endl after each line.

```
double picLen, picWid, colorPrice, perimeterOfFrame, area, total, framePrice ;
char frameType, color, crown, crownAmount ; 

//inputs//
cout << "Enter the length and width (in inches) of the picture : " ;
cin >> picLen, picWid ;
cout << endl ;
cout << "Enter the type of frame ('r' for regular, 'f' for fancy) : " ;
cin >> frameType ;
cout << endl ;
cout << "Choose the color (enter first letter of color name) : " ;
cin >> color ;
cout << endl ;
cout << "Do you want crowns on the sides? ('y' for yes and 'n' for no) : " ;
cin >> crown ;
cout << endl << endl ;

cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
```

Comment: After reading a line of input, call `getchar()`, maybe the end of line character is the problem.

Comment: First problem: `cin >> picLen, picWid` should be `cin >> picLen >> picWid`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing they often ignore in beginner C and C++ tutorials is that when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> there is an extra character added to the input stream.

If you don't manually get rid of this "end of line" (`\n`) character it can mess up your other input operations.

C++ has a method for doing this:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This will throw out any unprocessed characters until it encounters end of line, then it will throw out the end of line and stop, so you can call `cin >> myNextVar` again.

If `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` looks scary to you, just replace it with any big number like 256 for now.
It just says how many characters to ignore.
Usually, you will only need to ignore one, but its best to clear everything just in case.

More info here: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/